# Is eating fast food on regular basis really bad/harmful for health?

Tags: nutrition, diet, food-safety

I am talking about fast food from such popular chains as **KFC**, **McDonald's**, **Burger King** and similar.

Assortment of the chains typically include the following: hamburgers/whoppers, cheeseburgers, sandwiches, French fries (chips), fried chicken and so on.

---

Is eating such fast food on regular basis (3-5 times a week) really bad/harmful for health and may lead to sensible health problems. I'm not talking about weight gain or loss. I mean real problems with digestive apparatus, liver, pancreas, spleen or some vital organs causing further significant problems with health. It is also often stated that such food is carcinogenic and may lead to cancer.

---

Is it all close to truth or it is just a myth/stereotype?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: This is super broad. When a Dietitian does an analysis they usually break down a diet into its "components" the Macronutrients (Carbohydrate, Fat, Protein, Alcohol) and its Micronutrients (Vitamins & Minerals), not food type. A better question might be aimed at specific processed food and its links to a specific health issue: "Does eating processed hamburgers lead to cancer?" as your question currently covers everything from chicken poppers to milkshakes and is too broad.

Comment: I don't know enough about nutrition to provide what I feel is a proper answer, however the sheer SALT content in fast food (and hidden sugars) I know are very unhealthy (high sodium intake health info: https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/salt-and-sodium/sodium-health-risks-and-disease/). 

In addition to that, the weight gain you mentioned in the question IS a serious health problem that can lead to diabetes, sleep apnea, etc. Being overweight (obese) is a serious health problem in and of itself.